# Specify specific testcases in Python unit test TestLoader

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have the following folder structure.

```
Unit
    smoke.py
    Test1
         Test1.py
    Test2
         Test2.py
```

Both the test files have two test cases each.

File *smoke.py* contains

```
suite1 = unittest.TestLoader().discover('Test1', pattern = "Test*.py")
suite2 = unittest.TestLoader().discover('Test2', pattern = "Test*.py")
alltests = unittest.TestSuite((suite1, suite2))
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(alltests)
```

The above code runs four test cases which is expected.

Is there a way to run some specific test cases from file *test1.py* and *test2.py* where I can explicitly add those testcases to the suite1 and suite 2 in the above code.

If *Test1.py* contains a testcase name test_system in the class Test1, how can TestLoader load that specific test case instead of running all the testcases in that module.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can configure your test loader to run only tests with a certain prefix:

```
loader = unittest.TestLoader()
loader.testMethodPrefix = "test_prefix"# default value is "test"

suite1 = loader.discover('Test1', pattern = "Test*.py") 
suite2 = loader.discover('Test2', pattern = "Test*.py")
alltests = unittest.TestSuite((suite1, suite2))
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(alltests)
```

Answer (score 0):

A good solution for this is probably to get rid of `smoke.py` and instead install [nose](http://pythontesting.net/framework/nose/nose-introduction/). Nose is a test discovery framework which supports include / exclude rules.