# How to add all the tests whose name matches a pattern to a unit test suite?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest

I want to create multiple test suites based on the names of my unit tests, is it possible ?

The context is that I have a high number of unit test files with two types of tests : some check that returned values are corrects, and the others check that the value is calculated in a reasonable time.

Now I want to run the tests about timing on my machine, but not on my continuous integration builds on which only the first tests should be launched.

Hopefully all my timing tests have the same name (but are in different files): `test_problem_one_minute`

My tests are in a `unittest.TestCase` class.

Obviously I don't want to manually add all my tests in my test suite, there are too many of them. Is there a way to achieve this ? Or should I just use that pattern in the command line while calling python ?

Answer (score 1):

As said in this [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21115556/specify-specific-testcases-in-python-unit-test-testloader), one solution is to use a `TestLoader` and to modify its `testMethodPrefix` value :

**test_runner.py** :

```
# Loaders
loader_foo = unittest.TestLoader()
loader_bar = unittest.TestLoader()
loader_timing = unittest.TestLoader()

# Prefixes
loader_foo.testMethodPrefix = "test_problem_foo"
loader_bar.testMethodPrefix = "test_problem_bar"
loader_timing.testMethodPrefix = "test_problem_one_minute"

# Suites
suite_foo = loader_foo.discover('.', pattern="test_*.py")
suite_bar = loader_bar.discover('.', pattern="test_*.py")
suite_timing = loader_timing.discover('.', pattern="test_*.py")
suite_notiming = unittest.TestSuite((suite_foo, suite_bar))
suite_full = unittest.TestSuite((suite_foo, suite_bar, suite_timing))

# Running the correct test suite
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    if sys.argv[1] == "notiming":
       unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite_no_timing)
    elif [...]
```

And call `test_runner.py` like this :

> python test_runner.py notiming